# AriadneGraphQL - How to accept / return generic python dictionary

Tags: python, graphql, ariadne-graphql

I have recently started looking into integrating FastAPI with Ariadne to create an API. For simple type this is working fine but I am now looking to enable the user to save / retrieve any python dict using the API.

It's not clear to me how custom scalars could be leveraged to complete the operation.

I would have schema.graphql

```
scalar Generic

type UserData {
   name: String!
   data: Generic!
}
```

Where Generic could be any object which can be parsed as a Json dictionary.
I wonder what would be required in terms of resolver to persist and retrieve the data for this scenario ?

Comment: For those who are interested by the same topic graphene does offer the support for generic types. The integration is pretty seamless.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to introduce your `Generic` as a scalar type in your service's code, with `parse` and `serialize` methods that just passed through any value (or, by your description, any dictionary / JSON object) literally. That would then allow it to pass into and out of your GraphQL service.

To avoid doubt: this means you need to influence the available types for your service, rather than using a resolver to influence the behaviour of a particular field.

Comment: Thanks @Ed., indeed I don't even need to serialize the data for it to be read.
However, when trying to load saved data through GraphQl API, the json saved produces the following error: 

**String cannot represent value: {'test_field__1': 'hello', 'test_field__2': [1, 2, 3], 'test_field__3': {'sub_field__1': 'test_subfield'}}**

Comment: That looks like the GraphQL service thinks that's a `String` not a `Generic`. Need more information before anyone can fix this.